# Nested select not working in NHibernate.Linq

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I want to load the list of users and their roles, with this query:

```
var q = from u in session.Linq<User>()
    select new
    {
        u.Name,
        u.Password,                                
        Roles = from r in u.Roles
                select new { r.Code, r.Name }
    };
```

But this query is not working.
Produce the following error: "The method 'Select' is not implemented."

¿The message suggest that NHibernate.Linq not support nested selects?
I want to know if this is certain or exist other way to do this?

PD: please excuse my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

Current implementation of Linq provider is based on CriteriaApi and that why it can create only simple queries